# How to check a valid contact number in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to check a valid contact number:-

- The number may or may not start with a + sign.
- The number may contain `space` and hyphen (-) sign.
- There should be no consecutive hyphen (-) sign.
- There should be no other alphabets, special characters, etc.

An example of valid contact number is + 91-8341239834 or +91 033 2664 3271

The number must not exceed 20 characters.

How can I do this?

here is my code till now:-

```
preg_match('/^[0-9 .\-]+$/i', $number)
```

Comment: For US Based phone numbers, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation/

Comment: @Clomp, this application is not for US based phone numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped my quick reply. The link that I posted also contains this text in the original question: "Ideally it would handle international formats...". If you check that page out, you can find some pre-built regular expressions on it... which also handle international formats! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try `/^\+?(?:[0-9 ]{1,20}|([-])(?!\1))+$/` or `/(\+?[0-9 ]|([-])(?!\2))*$/` if preg supports beginning and end anchor tags or possibly `/\+?(?:[0-9 ]{7,20}|([-])(?!\1))+/`. This regex with `^` and `$` seems to satisfy all of your requirements as originally stated.

- `+ 9 2344235 23244` # match
- `+ 9-2344235-23244` # match
- `+923212312412424` # match
- `1231 231 23123213` # match
- `9--232314` # no match
- `82foo23123bar` # no match